# Quadrilateral ABCD is inscribed in a circle and its diagonals AC and DB intersect at P. If AB = 5, BP = 2 and CD = 6 find CP.

Tags: circles

I arrived at the answer CP = 12/5 units. Since ∆APB — ∆DPC. So there ratio is BP/CP = AB/DC, 2/CP = 5/6, 1/CP = 5/12, CP = 12/5.

Is this correct way to solve?

Comment: Yes it's all fine. What made you doubt your solution?

Comment: My teacher arrived at a different answer, so I have doubts about this question. I also have another question for her about a different problem, and I am confident that I am also correct.